# Controller not a function

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I started following [AngularJS CoffeeScript Style Guide](http://pastebin.com/CtG60iRR) and I'm getting errors about my controller not being a function, what am I doing wrong?

[controller.coffee](http://pastebin.com/CtG60iRR)

[app.js](http://pastebin.com/T13A9Epb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `controller` it should be,

```
angular.module('realEstate').controller('AggregateController', AggregateController);
```

Instead of,

```
 angular.module('app').controller('AggregateController', AggregateController);
```

Comment: Whops, totally missed it :D thank you, accepting your answer in 7 minutes!